# Android Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) with JNI code

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I am coding a game in C++ and SDL2 for Android. In Android 4.0.4 everything is fine. But in Android 5.1 i get a Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 12201 (SDLThread) when env->CallStaticVoidMethod is executed. I can't find a way to make it work.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_digit_appactivity_init(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
        // Obtain the Java class.
        env->GetJavaVM(&s_vm);
        LOGD("GetJavaVM Executed");

        libClass = env->FindClass("com/digit/appactivity");
        LOGD("FindClass Executed");


        // C++ => Java methods.
        javanamefunctionMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(libClass, "javanamefunction", "(I)V");
        LOGD("GetStaticMethodID Executed");

        return 0;
}


void android_paymoney(jint money)
{
        JavaVM* vm = ME_JavaVM();
        JNIEnv* env = 0;

        int vm_attached = vm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
        LOGD("GetEnv Executed");

        env->CallStaticVoidMethod(libClass,  javanamefunctionMethod, money); //here is the error
        LOGD("CallStaticVoidMethod Executed"); // this is not executed, app crashes
}
```

Comment: Does `FindClass` return a global or local JNI reference (I can't remember) ?

Comment: I have a jclass libClass; definition in the header file

Comment: It's not a C++ thing; the JNI `GetXXX` functions return either a global or a local JNI reference. Global references last until your code is unloaded, local references are only valid for the single C++ function call.  On return back to Java all local JNI references are release by the Java runtime.  So knowing the type of Java reference (global or local) a particular `GetXXX` returns is vital. References can also be converted, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#global_and_local_references

Comment: Richard, thanks for the info, but i still can't find what is happening. This code works fine in android 4.0.4 but not in android 5.1

Comment: Doing some research `FindClass` returns a local reference (which is release when the current JNI call returns). It was working in Android 4.0.4 by chance/luck.

Comment: See __Local and Global References__ here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Comment: Richard Critten thank you very very much. Your suggestions solved the problem. You are absolutely correct. When i put 'FindClass' together with 'CallStaticVoidMethod' it worked.